# Accumulation of APK's?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, apk

I just noticed a folder on the internal memory of my Samsung Galaxy S4 with name `SmsContactsBackup` that has an accumulation of APK's. You'd think that folder name indicates one of those Android backup programs, but, it appears to be multiple APK's with different version numbers, like the APK for each new version. They are consuming about 3 GB of memory space. Does Android normally store all of the updated APK's in storage? If so why this folder?

Answer (score 0):

No. This folder is not created by Android.

- This is the folder created by the app named `Super Backup & Restore`. This app is used to backup Contacts, SMS, Call logs, and some user Apps. And to restore to any version of android.
- During backup, it creates a root folder named `SMS Contacts Backups`, and with sub folders with each category: apks, logs, contacts, sms in the internal memory.
- You can remove those folders after restoring.(Note: Also, you need to remove App(Super Backup & Restore), otherwise it again creates folder with same name.)

Comment: Interesting but I don't recall backing up every new version of APK on my phone. There is literally three different versions of each APK. I can't see how this could have happened...

Comment: Do yo have used this app?

Comment: It's installed on my phone but I don't recall the last time I used it or even if I have. I downloaded some backup apps a while ago with the plan of making some backups. I just opened the app now and under the "apps" section it says archived next to many of the apps which I guess is all of the apks I see in that folder, I just don't recall initializing this...