# Removing SMScontactsbackup folder

Tags: external-sd

I have read a similar post here
[Accumulation of APK's?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/179152/accumulation-of-apks)

I have about 8Gb of my SDcard on a Samsung Galaxy S7 used by the apks folder within the SMScontactsbackup folder

Now from what I have read and understood (which may be wrong)

This apks folder contains the installation material for new versions of Android apps. Surely the apk should be deleted once the app upgrade has been successfully installed?

I don't have the Super Backup and Restore installed on the phone (which some people claim is the cause of the problem) but I can't be sure whether that app was installed in the past and now removed.

My question is

How do I delete this apks folder and its contents which are taking a large part of my SD card? I could not find those instructions anywhere - but maybe I missed them

Thanks

Clive

Comment: the folder is created by Super Backup and Restore app. It's used to backup and restore contacts ,sms, and apps. App backup contains only apk's, no data. Also, it backup's previous versions of app's apk which is updated on play store. You can surely delete that folder, if you're sure that you've installed all apk's and restored sms, contacts etc. You delete using any file manager app.

Comment: Also, check for  Super Backup and Restore in app list, and while uninstall it will ask permission for deleting backup folder data.

Comment: @Rahul. Thank you for taking the time to create a comment. You do not answer my questions. As I wrote in my original post , I do not have Super Backup up and Restore installed, so how can I delete it! Second, all I asked for are instructions on HOW to delete the apks folder. Again, that was clear in my original post. Do you know what I need to actually need to do or not? Thanks, Clive

Comment: have you tried deleting that folder using a file manger app(samsung file manger).

Comment: Hi Rahul, that has worked very well and freed up gigbytes of internal storage on the phone. Thanks for your help. Can you post your comment about using the file manager as a solution so I can mark it as solved and give you credit for your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Super Backup and Restore application creates a folder named SMScontactsbackup on internal storage. The application is used to backup and restore contacts, call logs, sms, apps etc.
- Each items are kept in separate folders.
- The app also saves  each  app's previous apk's which are updated through play store.
- You can delete this folder by these methods.

  1. By removing Super Backup and Restore application from your device, it will also ask permission whether to delete folder and it's contents.
  2. Using any file manager app (here Samsung file manager for Samsung devices),you can delete that folder from internal storage. (N.B if Super Backup and Restore application is not removed, then folder will be created again ).

Note: You need to make sure that, you've restored everything before removing app/ deleting folder.